# Form with collapsible blocks can not focus when block is collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a form with different collapsible blocks, when I am in the last field of the block and the next block is collapsed the arrow of the keyboard to go t9 the next field is disabled. I have done when I enter in this field with jquery mobile expand the next collapsible block, but the arrow is still disabled, how can I get to enable it? Any help would be appreciated.

The problem is that when the collapsible is closed, the arrow in the keyboard is disabled:

[image]

Only when is expanded is enabled when the field gets the focus. I have tried to expand it when the field gets the focus but still gets disabled.

The code:

HTML:

De quién
                                
                                
                             click to collapse contents

```
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" class="ui-listview">                    
                            <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child">
                                <label for="cuentaOrigen" class="labelSelect">Cuenta origen</label><div class="ui-select"><div id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaOrigen:cuentaOrigen-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow"><span class="{validate:{required:true}} controlCuenta">Selecciona una cuenta</span><select id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaOrigen:cuentaOrigen" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaOrigen:cuentaOrigen" class="{validate:{required:true}} controlCuenta" size="1" data-theme="" tabindex="1" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'change',0,'transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:remitente',{'onevent':actualizarDatos})"> <option value="">Selecciona una cuenta</option>
```

```
                            <li data-icon="false" class="sinBordeSeparador" id="enlaceReutilizarTransferencia" style="display: none;">
                                 <a class="ico_reutilizar reutilizar ui-btn" href="#">Reutilizar transferencia</a>
                            </li>                               

                            <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit">
                                <label for="remitente">Nombre del ordenante</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:remitente" type="text" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:remitente" value="COM PROP AVDA LANZAGORTA 38 ZALLA" class="{validate:{required:true,caracteresSepa:true,maxlength:40}} control" maxlength="40" placeholder="Nombre del ordenante" tabindex="2"></div>
                            </li>

                            <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador ultimo ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-last-child">
                                <label for="conceptoOrigen">Concepto para el ordenante</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:conceptoOrigen" type="text" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:conceptoOrigen" class="{validate:{required:true,caracteresSepa:true,maxlength:80}} control" placeholder="Concepto para el ordenante" tabindex="3" maxlength="80"></div>
                            </li>                                                           
                        </ul>
                </div></div>                                            
            </li>
```

Para quién
                            
                            
                         click to collapse contents

```
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" class="ui-listview">


                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child">
                            <label for="tipoCuentaDestino" class="labelSelect">???lbl_TipoCuentaDestino???</label><div class="ui-select"><div id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:tipoCuentaDestino-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow valid"><span>A una cuenta habitual</span><select id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:tipoCuentaDestino" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:tipoCuentaDestino" size="1" tabindex="4">  <option value="misCuentas" selected="selected">A una de mis cuentas</option>
<option value="cuentasHabituales">A una cuenta habitual</option>
<option value="otraCuenta">A otra cuenta</option>
```

```
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador otraCuenta ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="tipoTransferencia" class="labelSelect">Tipo de transferencia</label><div class="ui-select"><div id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:tipoOtraCuenta-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow"><span>Nacional</span><select id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:tipoOtraCuenta" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:tipoOtraCuenta" size="1" tabindex="5">    <option value="N" selected="selected">Nacional</option>
<option value="E">Extranjero</option>
```

```
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador misCuentas ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="cuentaDestino" class="labelSelect">Cuenta destino</label><div class="ui-select"><div id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaDestinoMiCuenta:cuentaDestinoMiCuenta-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow"><span class="{validate:{required:true,notEquals:['transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaOrigen:cuentaOrigen','Cuenta origen','Cuenta destino']}}">Selecciona una de mis cuentas</span><select id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaDestinoMiCuenta:cuentaDestinoMiCuenta" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaDestinoMiCuenta:cuentaDestinoMiCuenta" class="{validate:{required:true,notEquals:['transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaOrigen:cuentaOrigen','Cuenta origen','Cuenta destino']}}" size="1" data-theme="" tabindex="6">   <option value="">Selecciona una de mis cuentas</option>
```

```
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="cuentasHabituales ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: block;">
                            <label for="remitente">Cuenta destino</label><div class="ui-select"><div id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaDestinoHabitual-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow"><span class="{validate:{required:true}}">Selecciona una cuenta habitual</span><select id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaDestinoHabitual" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaDestinoHabitual" class="{validate:{required:true}}" size="1" tabindex="7">  <option value="">Selecciona una cuenta habitual</option>
```

```
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador otraCuenta ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: none;"> 

                            <label for="alias">Iban</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaDestino" type="number" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:cuentaDestino" class="{validate:{required: true, cuentaOIbanValido:true}} controlVal controlCuentaDestino conEventos1" oninput="limitarLongitud(event,35)" onkeydown="borrarCaracterDecimal(event)" placeholder="Iban" tabindex="8"></div>
                             <span class="spacer"></span>                           
                        </li>                       

                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador cuentasHabituales otraCuenta ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: block;">
                            <label for="beneficiario">Nombre del beneficiario</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:beneficiario" type="text" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:beneficiario" class="{validate:{required:true,caracteresSepa:true,maxlength:40}} controlVal" placeholder="Nombre del beneficiario" tabindex="9" maxlength="40"></div>
                        </li>

                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador misCuentas cuentasHabituales otraCuenta ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: block;">
                            <label for="conceptoDestino">Concepto para el beneficiario</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:conceptoDestino" type="text" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:conceptoDestino" class="{validate:{required:true,caracteresSepa:true,maxlength:80}} controlVal" placeholder="Concepto para el beneficiario" tabindex="10" maxlength="80"></div>

                        </li>                                   

                        <li class="sinBordeSeparador slider otraCuenta ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="guardarCuentaHabitual">Guardar como cuenta habitual</label><select id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:guardarCuentaHabitual" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:guardarCuentaHabitual" size="1" data-role="slider" onchange="mostrarCampoSlider(this);" tabindex="-1" class="ui-slider-switch">   <option value="false">No</option>
<option value="true">Sí</option>
```

SíNo

```
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador aliasCuentaHabitual ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="alias">Alias</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:alias" type="text" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:alias" class="{validate:{caracteresSepa:true}} controlVal" maxlength="40" placeholder="Alias" tabindex="11"></div>
                        </li>

                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador grupoInternacional otraCuenta extranjero ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="alias">NIF</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:nif" type="text" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:nif" class="{validate:{caracteresSepa:true}} controlVal" maxlength="10" placeholder="NIF" tabindex="12"></div>
                        </li>

                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador grupoInternacional otraCuenta extranjero ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="alias">Dirección </label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:direccion" type="text" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:direccion" class="{validate:{caracteresSepa:true}} controlVal" maxlength="30" placeholder="Dirección " tabindex="13"></div>
                        </li>

                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador grupoInternacional otraCuenta extranjero ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="alias">Población</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:poblacion" type="text" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:poblacion" class="{validate:{caracteresSepa:true}} controlVal" maxlength="30" placeholder="Población" tabindex="14"></div>
                        </li>                           

                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador grupoInternacional otraCuenta extranjero ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="alias">Código postal</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:codigoPostal" type="text" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:codigoPostal" class="{validate:{caracteresSepa:true,}} controlVal" maxlength="5" placeholder="Código postal" tabindex="15"></div>                             
                        </li>

                        <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="sinBordeSeparador grupoInternacional otraCuenta extranjero ui-field-contain ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-last-child" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="alias">BIC</label><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input id="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:bic" type="text" name="transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm:bic" class="{validate:{caracteresSepa:true}} controlVal" maxlength="15" placeholder="BIC" tabindex="16"></div>
                        </li>                                                                                                                                               

                    </ul>
                </div></div>
            </li>
```

Javascript: Here when I enter in the field conceptoOrigen if is collapsed, I expand it, but the downarrow of the keyboard is still disabled:

```
            $('#transferenciaIntroducirDatosForm\\:conceptoOrigen').on('focusin', function() {
                console.log("entrando último campo.");
                if($('#datosParaQuien').hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')) {
                    $('#datosParaQuien').collapsible({collapsed: false});

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't show any code, so I can be specific for your case, but for what you say I think the problem is that you can't set the focus to an element that is not displayed.

What you can do is handle the focus movement with your jquery code, so before setting the next focus, make sure its block is visible. Here you have an example...

**HTML**:

```
<input class='yourclass' />
<br/>
<fieldset>
  <input class='yourclass' />
  <br/>
  <input class='yourclass' />
</fieldset>
<br/>
<input class='yourclass' />
<br/>
<input class='yourclass' />
```

**CSS**:

```
fieldset { display: none; }
.uncollapse { display: block; }
```

**JQUERY**:

```
var lastInputPos = $(".yourclass").length - 1;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {

    if ( (e.keyCode == 38) || (e.keyCode == 40) ) { // Arrow UP&Down Keys.

        var focusPos = $('.yourclass').index($('.yourclass:focus'));
        var $nextFocusInput = null;

        if ( (e.keyCode == 40) && (focusPos < lastInputPos) )  // Key Arrow Down.
            $nextFocusInput = $('.yourclass').eq(focusPos+1);
        else if ( (e.keyCode == 38) && (focusPos > 0) )  // Key Arrow Up.
            $nextFocusInput = $('.yourclass').eq(focusPos-1);

        if ($nextFocusInput != null) {
            /* CODE FOR UNCOLLAPSING THE BLOCK OF THE NEXT INPUT FOCUSED */
            $('fieldset').removeClass('uncollapse');
            $nextFocusInput.closest('fieldset').addClass('uncollapse');
            /* ----------------------------------------------------- */
            $nextFocusInput.focus();
        }
    }
});
```

And the corresponding fiddle... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/798xny8n/1/

I think you can get the idea and adapt it to your case. Next time remember to show your code, to make easier to help you.

I hope it helps